# Check Username availability from two tables #MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, freeradius, radius

I have two tables (radcheck and otherusers) 
I would like to check if a user exists in "radcheck" table firstly
if the users is not there, I would like to check "otherusers" table.
This is what I did so far but every time I try there is an error or it doesn't work at all.
If you know a better way I could do it, it would be helpful as well. Thanks

```sql
authreply_table = radcheck
authreply_table2 = otherusers

nauthorize_reply_query = "\ 
  select id, username, attribute, value, op \ 
  from ${authreply_table} \ 
  CROSS JOIN ${authreply_table2} \
  where username = '%{sql-user-name}' \ 
  order by id"
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve them both at once, and examine `tbl` to see which table it came from.

```
select 1 as tbl, id, username, attribute, value, op \ 
  from ${authreply_table} \ 
  where username = '%{sql-user-name}' \ 
UNION
select 2, id, username, attribute, value, op \ 
 ${authreply_table2} \
  where username = '%{sql-user-name}' \ 
order by tbl,id
```